# What's the best practice with Codeigniter routes and sessions?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When using CI routes, I have the default route which points somewhere, but I want it to point to another place if the user is logged in.

Whats the best way of doing this?

**Edit**

I don't think I wrote this question as clearly as I should have. What I mean is that if the user is not logged in and they go to `www.domain.com/` they go to the home page. If they are logged in and they go to the same URL they see a different page, but the same URL in the address bar

Comment: I don't know about the best way to do this. But you could extend Controller with your own logic which redirects the user to somewhere if they are authenticated. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically as Malachi said, one way to do this is:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        if($this->auth_library->is_logged_in()) 
        { 
            redirect('my_logged_in_page');
        }
        // else...redirect to login?
    }

}

 // call it...   
class some_controller extends MY_Controller {
    // etc
}
```